# Admob shows on emulator but not device using Ionic

Tags: android, admob, ionic-framework

I followed this tutorial step by step: https://github.com/santonocito/angular-admobpro

it works pretty well on Android emulator but not on my Android device. I haven't change anything compared to this tutorial, this is exactly the same code.

Have you any idea ?
Thanks

Comment: i had a custom rom on my android device that was blocking adds, do you get the black bar but just no adds? or no black bar at all?

Comment: I have a custom rom too, but I can see Ads in other application.
I don't Ads at all, no black bar.
Thanks for answer

Comment: most likely it is a issue with the custom rom somehow blocking it or breaking the ads, see if you can borrow someones stock phone and test it. That is how if was able to see my ads working.

Comment: Great ! Thanks you so much. I borrow my friend's phone and AdMob works !

Comment: yeah no problem! it took me about a week to figure that one out :P if you could accept my answer I would greatly appreciate it :D

Comment: Done xD ! It doesn't cross my mind. I learnt something new. Thanks you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

most likely it is a issue with the custom rom somehow blocking it or breaking the ads, see if you can borrow someones stock phone and test it. That is how if was able to see my ads working.